# $\ast$-homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\phi: C(X,M_{4}(\mathbb{C})) \rightarrow C(Y,M_{8}(\mathbb{C})) $ be a $\ast$-homomorphism where $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be the C*-subalgebra of $C(X,M_{4}(\mathbb{C}))$. Can we conclude that $\phi(M_{2}(\mathbb{C}))$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question? How do you embed $ M_2 (\mathbb C) $? And of course the linearimage of a finite dimensional space is ffinite dimensional.

Comment: Pick an $x\in X$,  I was thinking of this embedding $\psi: C(\{x\},M_{2}(\mathbb{C}))\rightarrow C(X,M_{4}(\mathbb{C}))$ by $\psi(f)=diag(f\circ \mu,0)$ where $\mu:X\rightarrow \{x\}$ is continuous. But, can we say that $\phi(M_{2}(\mathbb{C}))$ is isomorphic to $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @user78800  Since your map is linear, martini's comment has answered the original question.  As for the new question in your comment, yes, $\phi$ is one-to-one and preserves the $*$-algebra structure.